# Redis model caching, when to call fetch_items in items_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, caching, model, redis

I am trying to use Redis as a caching layer between my app and a PostgreSQL db.

Please see below, my routes, items_controller, items_helper files. I'm confused about how #fetch_items in the items_helper is supposed to get called.

Presently, I am rendering jbuilder templates from all of my controller actions. I need to retain this functionality.

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :items
  get 'users/:id/sold_items' => 'users#sold_items'
  get 'categories/:id/available_items' => 'categories#available_items'

    get 'performances/:view' => 'performances#show'
```

items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    include ItemsHelper
  # Returns full list of items
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # Returns details for a single item
  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

items_helper

```
module ItemsHelper

    def fetch_items
        byebug
        items = $redis.get("items")
        if items.nil?
            items = Item.all.to_json
            $redis.set("items", items)
        end
        @items = JSON.load items
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `fetch_items` manually because this method is not going to be called automatically. Given the code, I suppose that you can replace

```
@items = Item.all
```

with

```
@items = fetch_items
```

to use the `fetch_items` method.

PS. The `fetch_items` method won't return an array of `Item` objects, only an array of hashes, so you might need to adjust other parts of the code as well.

I would recommend benchmarking whether using Redis in this particular situation is faster before making it to production.

Comment: great idea I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the rails guide "[caching with rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)" before starting to use redis by itself.

for example you could do something like:

```
cachekey = "items/#{Item.maximum(:updated_at)}"
@items = Rails.cache.fetch(cachekey, expires_in: 12.hours) do
  Item.all.as_json
end
```

The above code would keep a cache of all the items and stay updated to the most recent update. Probably wouldn't want to do this if your your items collection is huge, but worth considering.